# Android Tabbed application - List connected to Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-listview

I have the following in one of my tabs:

```
ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.countries);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
"List Item 1", "List Item 2", "List Item 3" };
```

This list is within a tab. I want to change it so when one of the items is clicked (say we call it London Big Ben, I want to somehow attach co-ordinates to that) it diverts to Google Maps either via WebView (easiest) or MapView appears over the tab (but the tab bar is still visible).

Can anyone provide links to tutorials or assistance?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code where i am put my data inside arraylist which i am fetching from Web Service.

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Name",name);
    map.put("Vicinity", vicinity);
    map.put("Latitude", lat);
    map.put("Longitude", lng);
    mylist.add(map);
}
```

After this below is the code of ListView Activity class. Where i have implemented on click listner and on click of listview calling another activity and passing the position of the list which is clicked.

**ListViewActivity Class code**

```
public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listingatms);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.listdata, 
                new String[] {"Name", "Vicinity"}, 
                new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent showMapMenusIntent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, MapMenus.class);
        showMapMenusIntent.putExtra("Position", position);
        startActivity(showMapMenusIntent);
    }
```

If you want to show the map in the same activity then use the postion variable and on the basis of that you can get all the values from mylist(ArrayList).

For e.g position = mylist.get(position).get("Name"));

This way you will be able to get all the details from ArrayList and use it as per your requirement.

Hope this will help you...